# How to write a loop in Python that outputs cinema ticket price based on user's age

Tags: loops, conditional-statements

I have just started writing loops in Python like this one:

```
prompt = "\nPlease enter the name of one of your favourite films: " 
prompt += "\n(Enter 'quit' when you have finished) "

while True:
  film = input(prompt)

  if film == 'quit':
    break
  else:
    print(f"I'd love to see {film.title()}!")
```

I now need to create a program that prompts the user for their age, and when they enter their age, it returns the admission price of the cinema ticket based on their age. I do not know how to incorporate multiple conditions into a loop like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to define functions and/or use dictionaries to handle the logic, I would recommend thinking of using multiple conditionals.

For example:

```
while True:
    age = int(input())
    age_0 = 0
    age_1 = 18
    age_3 = 65

    if age >= age_0 and age < age_1:
        print('ticket price: $10')
    elif age >= age_1 and age < age_2:
        print('ticket price: $20')
    elif age >= 65:
        print('ticket price: $15')
    else:
        ('Please provide a valid age')
```

Nonetheless I feel like you could have figured this one out by yourself. Hopefully this helped!